# Paperclip download file Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, download, paperclip

I am now able to upload files into my Rails app using Paperclip, but I was wondering if anyone could help me with how to download it? I have a Contract model that has an attachment called Avatar. So far I tried the following:

Currently I have a controller:

```
class DownloadController < ApplicationController

   def download_file
      send_file '@contract.avatar.url'
   end
end
```

In my contracts/show view I have:

```
 <%= link_to ('download'), {:controller => 'downloads', :action => 'download_file'})
```

My routes:

```
  get "downloads/download_file"
```

The error I am getting right now is "Uninitialized constant DownloadsController

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you have is pretty self-explanatory *if you know where to look*:

```
Uninitialized constant Download**s**Controller
```

---

**See how it's looking for a plural?**

There are two ways to solve this:

**Routes**

```
get "downloads/download_file", to: "download#download_file"
```

-

**Controller**

```
#app/controllers/downloads_controller.rb
class DownloadsController < ApplicationController
```